# Error: Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am getting the issue after reinstall my Xcode from 13.2 beta version to 13.2.1 release version, by-mistake I have deleted my project build folder & runner.

> Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing. No application
> found for TargetPlatform.ios. Is your project missing an
> ios/Runner/Info.plist? Consider running "flutter create ." to create
> one.

I also gone through it's suggestion

> flutter create .

but still having the same issue. my flutter doctor -v result is

> apple@apples-Mac-mini test_ios % flutter doctor -v
> [✓] Flutter
> (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale
> en-GB)
> • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/apple/Desktop/flutter_sdk/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 77d935af4d (12 days ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
> • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
> • Dart version 2.15.1
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
> • Android SDK at /Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
> • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
> • Xcode at /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • CocoaPods version 1.11.2
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
> • iPod touch (7th generation) (mobile) • A7FF5F55-96CF-4DD4-9790-6162A82AA0B7 • ios            •
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
> • Chrome (web)                         • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
>
> • No issues found!

also I have created the new flutter project from Android Studio but unfortunately it is also not containing the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Some how i found the files Runner.xcodeproj and Runner.xcworspace in bin and restoring them back solved my issues!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I manually deleted xcode profile using xcode IDE.
Please try the following:

1. Create a new flutter project.
2. Run the project - confirm its in good working order (you will see xcode compilation)
   3)I copied all files under ios folder of the new project to my current one & it worked like a charm.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not get solution online I had to try my own ways and it worked. This error occurs when you update Xcode. For me I downloaded the Xcode beta, and installed it then recreated the project
. You can extract if you have a backup. Then run Xcode beta simulator. That all. ALL the best.